# how to get array that contain certain value

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x

I'm new in solidity, I want to ask, in my case I want to store a data that may contain the same user ID but different value inside it each transaction, here is my smart contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.5;
contract userID{
  struct User {
        uint256 uid;
        bytes32 item;
      }
  mapping (uint256 => User) public  users;
  uint counter = 0;
  function sendReview(uint256 _uid, bytes32 _item) public{
      User storage useritem = users[counter];
      useritem.uid= _uid;
      useritem.item= item;
      counter++;
  }
   function getitem(**uint256 _uid**) public view returns( uint256, bytes32){
       **User storage users._uid**;
      return(users.uid, users.item);
  }
}
```

I want to get the item based on the *uid* that inserted into the function, how can I do it? I've tried a several way in *'User storage users._uid*' but didn't work at all, or is there any better way to do it?

EDIT:

I want store the data like:

```
user[0] = ["1","apple"]
user[1] = ["1","orange"]
user[2] = ["2", "grape"]
```

so the get function if I set the value of *uid* into 1 then the result will be:

```
["1","apple"],
["1","orange"]
```

Comment: in your question you indicate that the data may include several items with the same uid. If you search for items based on the uid your search may return several results, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, that's what I looking for, so It will return several results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a counter, just create a mapping of the uid to a byte32 array of userItems. Then when getting the items, you provide the uid and you get the list of items for that user.

This can be achieved with the code below. I test it on remix.

```
pragma solidity 0.5;
contract userID{
 
mapping (uint256 => bytes32[]) public  users;

function sendReview(uint256 _uid, bytes32 _item) public{
    users[_uid].push(_item);
}

function getitem(uint256 _uid) public view returns(bytes32[] memory){
    return(users[_uid]);
    
}

}
```

If you want to return structures then you can use this:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
pragma solidity 0.5;
contract userID{

struct user {
    uint256 uid;
    bytes32 item;
} 

mapping (uint256 => user[]) public  users;

function sendReview(uint256 _uid, bytes32 _item) public{
    user memory newUser = user(_uid,_item);
    users[_uid].push(newUser);
}

function getitem(uint256 _uid) public view returns(user[] memory){
    return(users[_uid]);

}

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what if the data type that will be inserted not only bytes32? is that possible? or there is a data type to replace the "bytes32" as an array? In this case the array will store 2 value, uid as uint256 and item as bytes32

Comment: you can use an array of structs, but you will be adding redundant information by adding again the user id, no? The way I presented it makes it clear that the array of bytes32 is indexed by an unique user id.

Notice that you will use as input uid and you will get the same uid number in one of your responses. There is no need to do this and will cost you 20000 gas extra per transaction when using the `sendReview` function

Comment: yes, I know, but I'm trying to try what if I input multiple data not only one kind of data, its just for study purposes, I don't mind about gas, yet, thank you by the way

Comment: See my updated answer for recovering the structure. Hope this helps

Comment: I'm sorry, but my cakeshop compiler shows error `UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "components" (class com.jpmorgan.cakeshop.model.ContractABI$Entry$Param), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "indexed", "type", "name", "internalType"])` I tried to google it, but can't find anything

Comment: This works without problems. I deployed it using remix. Notice that to return structures you need the experimental ABIencoderV2.

Comment: Okay then, maybe I will try to use the Remix instead of cakeshop, thanks for your answer, I'm sorry to bother you, may I ask you again if I face some trouble again? Thanks a lots

Comment: No problem, I am happy to help.